# Solve the initial value problem $9y''(t)-2y'(t)+y(t)=t\cdot e^{-t/4}; y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$ using Laplace transformations

Tags: laplace-transform

Solve the initial value problem $9y''(t)-2y'(t)+y(t)=t\cdot e^{-t/4}; y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$ using Laplace transformations

I rearranged for $\bar y(s)=\dfrac{1}{(s+1/4)^2(9s^2-2s+1)}+\dfrac{9}{(9s^2-2s+1)}$

For the first term I solved using partial fractions and obtained:

$\bar f_1(s)=\dfrac{1664}{1089(s+1/4)}+\dfrac{16}{33(s+1/4)^2}-\dfrac{1664s}{121(9s^2-2s+1)}+\dfrac{2380}{1089(9s^2-2s+1)}$

When I tried finding the inverse Laplace of these, the first two terms were fine but when I reached the 3rd and 4th term I felt like the amount of work required was worth too much for what it's worth... have I made a mistake anywhere?

For the second term, I obtained:

$f_2(t)=e^{t/9}\cdot \dfrac{9}{2\sqrt2} \cdot \sin (\dfrac{2\sqrt2}{9})$

edit1: fixed partial fraction decomposition

Comment: I think that the second fraction in the partial fraction decomposition has no square in the denominator ...

Comment: @JeanMarie I had a look over and had a square in the denominator of the first term but I think it should be there for the second term?

Comment: For the quadratic in the denominator which has no simple roots, use the canonical decomposition $9(s-1/9)^2-....$

Comment: I said "the second term" but I didn't  check.   It is likely to be the first one...

Comment: @JeanMarie To find the coefficients for the 3rd and 4th fraction I equated the cubic and square coefficients - I think these values are right as I checked on Wolfram

Comment: Write the denominator as $9\left((s-1/9)^2+8/81\right).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting
$$ \dfrac{s}{9s^2-2s+1}=\frac19\frac{s}{(s-\frac19)^2+(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9})^2},\dfrac{1}{9s^2-2s+1}=\frac19\frac{1}{(s-\frac19)^2+(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9})^2}$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&L^{-1}(\dfrac{s}{9s^2-2s+1})\\
&=&\frac19L^{-1}(\frac{s}{(s-\frac19)^2+(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9})^2})\\
&=&\frac19L^{-1}(\frac{s-\frac19}{(s-\frac19)^2+(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9})^2})+\frac1{2\sqrt2}L^{-1}(\frac{\frac{2\sqrt2}{9}}{(s-\frac19)^2+(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9})^2})\\
&=&\frac19e^{\frac19t}\cos(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9}t)+\frac1{2\sqrt2}e^{\frac19t}\sin(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9}t)
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
&&L^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{9s^2-2s+1})\\
&=&\frac1{2\sqrt2}L^{-1}(\frac{\frac{2\sqrt2}{9}}{(s-\frac19)^2+(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9})^2})\\
&=&\frac1{2\sqrt2}e^{\frac19t}\sin(\frac{2\sqrt2}{9}t)
\end{eqnarray}